# Apply search on field1 if exists and Ingnoring field2 else search on field2 elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Have two fields in index. Lets assume as field1 and field2.

- **search  cases**

  - both might present
  - field1 or field2 might present
  - fiels1 and field2 might present

Here I have to create a query like

- If field1 exist apply search on it and ignore field2
- if field1 doesn't exists apply search on field2
- if both exist apply search only on field1 ignore field2

can someone help with query

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is 1 `should` consisting of 3 `must`s:

```
GET conditionals/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "field1"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field1": "abc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "field1"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field2": "xyz"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "field1"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "field2"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field2": "xyz"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```